# Creating Bounding boxes for contours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.1

I used this code to draw "Bounding boxes". Now I want the largest rectangle while there are many rectangles. After finding the largest rectangle, I want to have the coordinates of this rectangle. By these coordinates, I want to be a part of the original image.The largest rectangle is my car.

```
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 0;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void*);
/** @function thresh_callback */
void thresh_callback(int, void*)
{
    Mat threshold_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    /// Detect edges using Threshold
    threshold(src_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    /// Find contours
    findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    /// Approximate contours to polygons + get bounding rects and circles
    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
    vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
    vector<Point2f>center(contours.size());
    vector<float>radius(contours.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
        boundRect[i] = boundingRect(Mat(contours_poly[i]));
        minEnclosingCircle((Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i]);
    }


    /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects + circles
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());
        rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
    }

    /// Show in a window
    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawing);
}
/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread("RGB2YCrCb_BC_SB.png");
    /// Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));
    /// Create Window
    char* source_window = "Source";
    namedWindow(source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(source_window, src);


    thresh_callback(0, 0);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

I have worked hard and I have searched a lot.Please help if you can.
See the picture.

**Input image:**

[image]

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: How much of this code do you actually understand? Because the rectangles are already computed in your code, all you have to do is to multiply height by width to get the area, and find the largest one.

Comment: I do not know how to do that !!

Answer (score 3):

Src:

[image]

Find the max-area bounding-rect of approxed-poly-contours:

[image]

Cropped:

[image]

---

Code with comments:

```
//! 2018.05.13 13:31:34 CST
//! Find the max-area bounding-rect of approxed-poly-contours

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int findMaxRect(){
    /// Read, cvtColor, threshold
    Mat img, gray, threshed;
    img = imread("car.jpg");
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(gray, threshed, 100, 255, THRESH_OTSU|THRESH_BINARY);

    /// Find contours
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(threshed, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    ///  Find the max boundingRect of approxed-contours
    double max_area = -1;
    Rect max_rect;
    int idx = -1;
    vector<Point2f> contour_poly;

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
        /// Approx the contour
        Mat contour = Mat(contours[i]);
        double arclen = arcLength(contour, true);
        approxPolyDP(contour, contour_poly, 0.03*arclen, true);

        /// Get the bounding box
        Rect rect =  boundingRect(Mat(contour_poly));

        /// Update the max_area_box
        double area = rect.width*rect.height;
        if(area>max_area){
            max_area = area;
            max_rect = rect;
        }
    }

    cout << max_rect<<endl;

    /// Draw the max rect
    Mat drawing = img.clone();
    rectangle(drawing, max_rect.tl(), max_rect.br(), Scalar(0,255,0), 1,8,0);
    /// Crop
    Mat dst = img(max_rect);
    /// Display
    imshow("drawing", drawing);
    imshow("dst", dst);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    //test_contours();
    findMaxRect() ;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you dear friend.My problem has been resolved.